# Issues with updating PHP session variable via AJAX in WampServer

Tags: javascript, php, session

I am facing an issue with updating a PHP session variable using AJAX in a WampServer environment. Here's a brief overview of the problem:

I have an HTML element with a data attribute that contains a username:

```
<img class="modal-link editar-usuario-btn" src="../img/pruebas/lapiz.png" alt="Editar" data-nombre-usuario="<?= $usuario['usuario'] ?>">
```

When this element is clicked, it triggers an AJAX call to a PHP script (muestra-usuario-seleccionado.php) that updates a session variable with the provided username:

```
$('.editar-usuario-btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nombreUsuario = $(this).data('nombre-usuario');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../scripts/muestra-usuario-seleccionado.php',
        data: { nombreUsuario: nombreUsuario },
        success: function(response) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
            if (jsonData.success === 1) {
                console.log('Script executed successfully.');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('Error in AJAX call:', error);
        }
    });

    $('#edit-user-modal').modal('show');
});
```

The PHP script (muestra-usuario-seleccionado.php) looks like this:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['nombreUsuario'])) {
    $_SESSION['usuario-a-editar'] = $_POST['nombreUsuario'];
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'usuario' => $_SESSION['usuario-a-editar']));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'error' => 'Username not received'));
}
```

The issue arises when attempting to retrieve and display this session variable in another part of the application within a modal:

```
<!-- Modal 7 - Editar usuario -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="edit-user-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="edit-user-modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="edit-user-modal-title">Opciones de usuario para <span id="usuario-mostrado"></span></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="post" id="cambia-nivel-usuario" class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center mt-3">
                            <input type="hidden" id="nombre-usuario-hidden" value="">
                            <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario-a-editar']?>
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Nivel</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php 
                                            $i = 1;
                                            $niveles = getNivelesMenorQueAdmin($nivelAdmin);
                                            $usuarioNombre = $_SESSION['usuario-a-editar'];
                                            foreach ($niveles as $nivel):     
                                            $nivel = $nivel['nivel'];   
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td><?= $i++ .' '. $nivel ?></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="radio">
                                                    <label>
                                                    <input type="radio" name="nivel" value="<?= $nivel ?>" <?php if (getNivelPorUsuario($usuarioNombre) == $nivel) echo 'checked'; ?>>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group mt-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded" style="width: 155px">Guardar cambios</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal 7 - Editar usuario -->
```

This line `$usuarioNombre = $_SESSION['usuario-a-editar'];` should print the username correctly but the session variable seems to be wrong. This modal is used in order to see the user level and change it if its necessary. However, due to the session variable not capturing the correct username value, it fails to display the indicated user's level, making it impossible to modify. Consequently, the user level remains inaccessible for editing as the session variable does not accurately reflect the selected username.

I've confirmed that the PHP error logs correctly show the username at the appropriate point. I suspect there might be a session-related or caching issue, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Is this a JS, a PHP, or an HTML problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: This issue is primarily related to PHP because I am unable to display the session variable with the correct username consistently.

I have implemented logging statements, enhancing error handling, and verifying the session variable's contents

Comment: Does the "_other part of the application_" use `session_start()`?

Comment: And when is the modal build in PHP? Before or after the AJAX call to set the user name?

Comment: @brombeer yes, it is used.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the modal is shown once the session variable is stablished.
The user is selected -> Ajax -> PHP (Updates de variable.) -> Ajax got an asnwer of success or error -> Shows modal

Comment: When you **show** the modal is somewhat irrelevant, since the session variable comes from PHP. That's why I asked _"when is the modal build in PHP"_. For instance, when it is part of, and build into, the page that uses the AJAX call and shows the modal, then the modal will be build before the session variable is set.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware do you mean where is literally written the modal? my php has this structure.
html (the page)
modals
JavaScript (<script>)
Then, the modal is created before de AJAX

Comment: I cannot make sense of what you're writing in the previous comment. Anyway, make sure you know the distinction between what is done "server-side" and what is done "client-side", because you don't seem to make that distinction. See: https://www.lytics.com/blog/client-side-vs-server-side-everything-you-need-to-know/ If you think you understand it have another look at your code, consider the consequences of what's done on the server and what's done on the client. If you think you know what's going on, check it to make sure.

Answer (score -2):

An easy fix would be pushing the user session variable together with the data from the image through ajax. You can verify the session variable in your script to make sure it is passed back to the modal.

Comment: Isn't that what is already doing in `...'usuario' => $_SESSION['usuario-a-editar']`? And that still wouldn't allow OP to run `getNivelPorUsuario($usuarioNombre)` _on the server/in PHP_ again

Comment: The idea to update the modal with the value returned from the AJAX call is a valid one. This is then done on the client in Javascript.

Comment: then he should check if the session variable is passed to the html from PHP